# WCF Service Error 500 0 121

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a  client WCF service (myservice.svc) which is hosted (IIS 7.5) on my local machine and it is working fine locally. I am also am able to browse this service from remote machines sucessfully.

I have another handler application i.e Order.ashx hosted in a remote server.This handler is configured to hit the above service using the WCF endpoint configurations.

### Config:-

```
bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" contract="MYContract" name="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync">
```

Now, above handler will be called by a third party service and as a result it generates some 'xxxx.xml' (500 kb) file in specific folder in the same remote server.

### Problem:-

Now my service (i.e myservice.svc - which is in local machine) main task is pick that 'xxxx.xml' file from the above folder and pass it to BizTalk application which is on my local machine.

I have also given 'All permissions to Everyone & System' to that folder in remote machine.

So, During this process I am encountered with '500 0 121 1356707' error (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1).

```
IIS Log:-
------------
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
Version: 1.0
Date: 2014-10-07 13:28:41
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2014-10-07 13:28:41 111.xx.xxx.xx POST /local/myservice.svc - 80 - xx.xx.xx.xx (remote server IP) - 500 0 121 1356707
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
```

Also, I have encountered a time out issue from the handler application:- Getting the same error even when the time out value is increased to 1 hour.

```
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:09:59.2968750.
Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout
value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion
of a longer timeout., System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to xxx.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a 500 error (HTTP Status 500), not a 500 0 121 1356707 error (the last 3 numbers per the field list are sc-substatus, sc-win32-status and time-taken).   Check the event viewer on the server - HTTP 500 response means there was an error on the server - chances are something went wrong in your service.

Comment: Hello Tim Thanks for reply. There are no errors in event viewer either in local or remote server regarding this issue. And about service, it is working fine in another environment & able to browse successfully in remote server with my machine URL. So there is no issue with the service.